# The direction does not show my current location and the destination

Tags: google-maps

See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXI3f.png).

I try to show my current location to the destination but the direction does not show up in the map, it just show the route at panel only.

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            draggable: true,
            map: map,
            panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
        });
        var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
        var mapOptions =
        {
            zoom: 15,
            center: coords
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        displayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);


        function displayRoute(service, display) {
            service.route({
                origin: coords,
                destination: new google.maps.LatLng(5.409722, 100.313319),
                provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    display.setDirections(response);
                } else {
                    alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The map does not show the direction from my current location to destination.

Comment: are you doing this thing on android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer`, the map is undefined.  Either create the `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` after the map, or call `.setMap` on it once the map is defined.

```
  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: coords
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
  });
  displayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj9mp998/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
// [ 0 ]: Tapah, Perak, Malaysia (4.19773, 101.261529)

function initialize() {
  var latitude = 4.19773;
  var longitude = 101.261529;
  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: coords
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
  });
  displayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);


  function displayRoute(service, display) {
    service.route({
      origin: coords,
      destination: new google.maps.LatLng(5.409722, 100.313319),
      provideRouteAlternatives: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        display.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="right-panel"></div>
```